# File not found when trying to read

Tags: java, file-io

**Code:**

```
public class problem_7_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Input file: ");
       String inputFileName = console.next();

       File inputFile = new File("\"" + inputFileName + "\"");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    }
}
```

I am trying to prompt the user to enter a file to read. When the file is entered, it brings up an error saying the file is not found. I have the file saved on my program so it should be there. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the directory for the files to be loaded?

Comment: Excuse me as I am a beginner, but what does this mean? I have a text file in my program called "numbers.txt" that I need to enter when prompted.

Comment: OK. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is wrong.  Why are you adding quotes to the file name?  Should be:

```
File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line right after creating inputFile and make sure it is the correct path. If not, modify it to match the location on the disc

`System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
```

inputFileName is String already so you don't need to put it in quotes